# Read value of tag <PACKAGE>. How?

Tags: regex, abap

I have following code:

```
<TASKDATA>
<PACKAGE>BADI BS Aggr Profit Centers to Entity</PACKAGE>
<TEAM/>
<GROUP>Financial Process</GROUP>
<APPSET>OneMIS_DEV</APPSET>
<APPLICATION>Planning_DEV</APPLICATION>
<ANSWERPROMPT>%SELECTION% 
|DIMENSION:CATEGORY|AC0|DIMENSION:P_ENTITY||10DIMENSION:TIME|2019.09
%SELECTION_KEYDATE% </ANSWERPROMPT>
</TASKDATA>
</LINK_PROCESS>
<LINK_PROCESS LINK_TYPE="BPC_PACKAGE">
<PROPERTY NAME="NAME">Deconsolidation</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="DESCRIPTION">Deconsolidation (Static Comp Code 
Filter)</PROPERTY>
<PROPERTY NAME="ID">583FA498C7BE45D4BECFF0F73FADA10B</PROPERTY>
<TASKDATA>
<PACKAGE>Deconsolidation</PACKAGE>
<TEAM/>
<GROUP>Financial Process</GROUP>
<APPSET>OneMIS_DEV</APPSET>
<APPLICATION>Planning_DEV</APPLICATION>
<ANSWERPROMPT>%SELECTION%
|DIMENSION:CATEGORY|AC0|DIMENSION:P_ENTITY|CZ20|27DIMENSION:TIME|2019.09 %SELECTION_KEYDATE% </ANSWERPROMPT>
</TASKDATA>
```

I need to select only the strings P_ENTITY which are under the tag Deconsolidation. For example in the example the string P_ENTITY at row 9 must be skipped because above there is the tag BADI BS Aggr Profit Centers to Entity. On the other side the string P_ENTITY at row 26 must be selected because above there is the tag Deconsolidation   How can I do?.

I have tried with the regex `P_ENTITY.{1,1}([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2},*)*` but it selects all P_ENTITY strings.

Comment: Something like `(?s)<PACKAGE>Deconsolidation</PACKAGE>(?:(?!</?PACKAGE>).)*?P_ENTITY\|\K[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}` [can be used](https://regex101.com/r/GvsD2T/1), but why not use an XML parser first to grab plain text from the required nodes?

Comment: `Deconsolidation` and `BADI BS Aggr Profit Centers to Entity` are not tags, they are text. You should use a proper parser (XML?) for this kind of activity, in order to get good results. Regex is not at all a good parser, for several reasons.

Comment: Better to use an XML parser, iterate over the object and skip the package item with bad on it.

Comment: Wiktor. Great solutions. it works, but your regex isn't accepted by ABAP ;-(

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have fully valid XML, i.e. your XML has wrapping parent tag for `<LINK_PROCESS>` tags

```
<LINKS>
    <LINK_PROCESS LINK_TYPE="BPC_PACKAGE">
        <TASKDATA>
            <PACKAGE>BADI BS Aggr Profit Centers to Entity</PACKAGE>
            <TEAM/>
            <GROUP>Financial Process</GROUP>
            <APPSET>OneMIS_DEV</APPSET>
            <APPLICATION>Planning_DEV</APPLICATION>
            <ANSWERPROMPT>%SELECTION% |DIMENSION:CATEGORY|AC0|DIMENSION:P_ENTITY||10DIMENSION:TIME|2019.09%SELECTION_KEYDATE% </ANSWERPROMPT>
        </TASKDATA>
    </LINK_PROCESS>
    <LINK_PROCESS LINK_TYPE="BPC_PACKAGE">
        <PROPERTY NAME="NAME">Deconsolidation</PROPERTY>
        <PROPERTY NAME="DESCRIPTION">Deconsolidation (Static Comp Code Filter)</PROPERTY>
        <PROPERTY NAME="ID">583FA498C7BE45D4BECFF0F73FADA10B</PROPERTY>
        <TASKDATA>
            <PACKAGE>Deconsolidation</PACKAGE>
            <TEAM/>
            <GROUP>Financial Process</GROUP>
            <APPSET>OneMIS_DEV</APPSET>
            <APPLICATION>Planning_DEV</APPLICATION>
            <ANSWERPROMPT>%SELECTION%|DIMENSION:CATEGORY|AC0|DIMENSION:P_ENTITY|CZ20|27DIMENSION:TIME|2019.09 %SELECTION_KEYDATE% </ANSWERPROMPT>
        </TASKDATA>
    </LINK_PROCESS>
</LINKS>
```

you can parse your XML with below ST transformation `zdecon`

```
<?sap.transform simple?>
<tt:transform xmlns:tt="http://www.sap.com/transformation-templates" template="main">
  <tt:root name="ROOT"/>
  <tt:template name="main">
   <LINKS>
    <tt:loop name="line" ref="ROOT">
      <LINK_PROCESS>
      <tt:skip name="PROPERTY" count="*" />
        <TASKDATA>
          <PACKAGE>
            <tt:value ref="package"/>
          </PACKAGE>
          <tt:skip count="4"/>
          <ANSWERPROMPT>
            <tt:value ref="answer"/>
          </ANSWERPROMPT>
        </TASKDATA>
      </LINK_PROCESS>
    </tt:loop>
    </LINKS>
  </tt:template>
</tt:transform>
```

and call it like this in ABAP:

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF entity,
        package TYPE string,
        answer TYPE string,
      END OF entity,
      tt_entities TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF entity WITH DEFAULT KEY.

DATA: xml_string TYPE string.
DATA: tab        TYPE tt_entities.

xml_string = ` <LINKS><LINK_PROCESS LINK_TYPE="BPC_PACKAGE"> ` &&
` <TASKDATA> ` &&
...
`   </TASKDATA> ` &&
`   </LINK_PROCESS></LINKS>`.

CALL TRANSFORMATION zdecon
             SOURCE XML xml_string
             RESULT root = tab.

DELETE tab WHERE package <> 'Deconsolidation'.

LOOP AT tab ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<line>).
  SPLIT <line>-answer AT '|' INTO TABLE DATA(deconsolidations).
  FIND REGEX '.+P_ENTITY' IN TABLE deconsolidations MATCH LINE DATA(l).
  WRITE: deconsolidations[ l + 1 ].
ENDLOOP.
```

Several assumptions that have been made for your XML:

1. `<PROPERTY>` tag is arbitrary and may be missing
2. `<ANSWERPROMPT>` tag contains list of dimensions wrapped in %SELECTION% placeholders
3. Every dimension comes in form of `|DIMENSION:<dim_name>|<dim_value>|`
4. Random numbers before DIMENSION keyword are insignificant and can be ignored

> **27**DIMENSION:TIME